# How do you send an HTTP Shipping Request in Magento2 from a custom shipping module?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I have created a custom shipping module and it's working perfectly, but I cannot figure out how to send the shipping info via a REST API request to the shipping company's website. I tried to emulate the Fedex and UPS modules, but there has to be an easier way. I am new to the MVC architecture, so I'm having some trouble understanding.

Specifically what I am trying to do is have the API request trigger when the user finalizes their order placement. The request would only trigger if the shipping code chosen matched the custom shipping module's code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe FedEx and UPS do not support RESTful APIs. You can try out REST API wrapper like [Postmen](https://www.postmen.com) that supports UPS, FedEx and more couriers in one integration. That could make integration more easily. Postmen does support [PHP library](https://docs.postmen.com/) which could help you integrate with Magento faster.

Comment: Hey thanks. I actually have my own shipping company that I work for that we're trying to send the API request to. I have the API built, but I just need to figure out where in Magento's architecture I actually make the shipping request.

Comment: I have the same problem. Saddly there is no answe here, :(